# How to get Template Rendered function to work when not using {{#each}}

Tags: templates, meteor, each, meteor-blaze

So, I have been trying to figure out how to use the rendered function in Meteor since upgrading to 0.8.0. Blaze changes the behavior of the rendered function and [now it is only called once](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#rendered-callback-only-fires-once).

In looking for help I have found 2 examples that explain how to get the old functionality with this new method. [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes), look at the section entitled "New Rendered behaviour with external scripts e.g. jQuery." And Avital's [github repo](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback) showing two new ways to deal with the problem.

However, none of these worked for me. My problem out was that I wasn't looping through content with an {{#each}} block. I was only needing to run rendered on on iteration of information. So, with the above examples rendered would be called each time a new item was added to the database. But this wouldn't work for me since I just needed to display the information and run some jquery styling stuff once the page had rendered.

All this to say I figured out that if I check to see if the data has content the rendered function works correctly for me. I have a [repo](https://github.com/yankeyhotel/meteor-rendered-test) with the below files if anyone wants to check out what I did.

Basically what is happening below is that the manipulations that happen in the "justName" rendered function work when called in the {{#each data}} and {{#if data}} blocks, but happen too quickly if neither is use. This might make sense for someone who understands this (i dont), but it does seem to function this one.

**HTML**

```html
<template name="infoEach">
{{#each data}}
    <ul>
        <li class="name">{{> justName}}</li>
    </ul>
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="infoIf">
{{#if data}}
    <ul>
        <li class="name">{{> justName}}</li>
    </ul>
{{/if}}
</template>

<template name="infoNothing">
<ul>
    <li class="name">{{> justName}}</li>
</ul>
</template>

<template name="justName">
    <span class="justName">{{name}}</span>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
// Collection
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items");

// Fixture
if (Items.find().count() === 0) {
    Items.insert({ name: "Matt" });
    Items.insert({ name: "Karen" });
}

// Info Each
Template.infoEach.helpers({
    data: function() { return Items.find(); }
});
Template.infoEach.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.$(".name").text());
}

// Info If
Template.infoIf.helpers({
    data: function() { return Items.findOne({name: "Matt"}); }
});
Template.infoIf.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.$(".name").text());
}

// Info Nothing
Template.infoNothing.helpers({
    data: function() { return Items.findOne({name: "Matt"}); }
});

Template.infoNothing.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.$(".name").text());
}


// Just name
Template.justName.rendered = function() {
    var ran = Random.choice(["blue", "red", "orange"]);
    var txt = this.$(".justName").text();

    this.$(".justName").text(txt + " " + ran);
    this.$(".justName").addClass("added").css("color", ran);

    console.log(this.$(".justName").text());
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. In this example the rendered function on the "infoNothing" template is called before all of the others.
2. The method using in the Avital's [github repo](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback) he uses "Items = new Meteor.Collection("items", {connection: null});" which did work with the "infoNothing" template, however if I used a more typical connection then it would fail.

Hopefully this will provide some insight into the new rendered function. And if I got anything wrong or someone has got better (more experienced) information please comment. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the rendered callback to fire more than once? I've read through your question multiple times now, and am struggling to figure out the answer.

Comment: I am still having issues so any help would certainly be appreciated, I thought the above example would be more helpful than it actually is.

A brief explanation of my problem. I am loading in a <p>{{name}}</p>. Once the {{name}} variable is placed in the doc, I want to alter it with jquery, specifically enable inline editing. But the rendered function continually fires before the variables are loaded in rendering the jquery used to create the inline editing forms empty. So to sum up, the rendered function isn't waiting on the data to fire and I can't figure out how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about putting your jQuery code inside the rendered callback of the outer template? The "justName" template gets rendered for every name in your collection, so if you have 10 names...it's going to fire once every time that template is rendered...10 names = 10 times. The outer template will only fire the render callback when all inner templates have rendered.

Comment: @fletch yeah that is how I had it set up originally, but the problem is that using that method the jquery methods are called before the data is available in the templates. So, it doesn't work at all. I went into a little more detail about my specific problem on this post a couple of days ago and still have no idea what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. Thanks again for the help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867690/how-do-i-use-x-editable-on-dynamic-fields-in-a-meteor-template-now-with-blaze

Comment: I played around with your source code tonight. I see what you are saying now. My understanding "was" that the outer template wouldn't fire the rendered until all inner templates had rendered...that was incorrect. Looks like the outer doesn't wait around. Even UI.body.rendered is fired before the majority of templates are rendered. I'm going to throw this past a colleague at work, and see what he has to say.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please, let me know if I can explain anything else. If you'd like to just email me you can, my email address is yankeyhotel at gmail.

Comment: @fletch not that you need any more of an explanation, but I tried to simplify the issue I was having down to it's simplest form here on this [repo](https://github.com/yankeyhotel/meteor-rendered-test2). FYI I'm using the new Iron Router along with Blaze and Meteor 0.8.0. It seems like if you have a {{#each something}} {{> item}} {{/each}} block and use the rendered function on the {{> item}} template it will work, but if you are just looking at a single {{item}} page rendered always fires too early. Thanks again.